# Kong-proxy not working inside Jelastic environment

Tags: linux, load-balancing, kubernetes, kong

We need a bit of help trying to install Kong in Kubernetes inside Jelastic environment. Me and My colleague have a production based kubernetes cluster with the following:

- Load Balancer

  - 1 Node with Public IP
- Workers

  - 2 Nodes
- Storage

  - 3 Nodes with NFS storage
- Control Plane

  - 3 Nodes

---

By default, this environment has `ingress-nginx` which loads the `Hello Kuberenetes` application just fine. Here is the config for the ingress-nginx hello kubernetes example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: hello-kubernetes
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

However, when we install `Kong` and switch the ingress class to `Kong`, it returns 404. Some context on how we install Kong:

1. Setting the config for the `metallb-system` and assign the public ip address:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - XXX.XXX.XXX.35-XXX.XXX.XXX.35
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
  namespace: metallb-system
```

2. Restarting the controller and the pods in the `metallb-system` name-space
3. Installing Kong using the `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/main/deploy/single/all-in-one-postgres.yaml`
4. It gets assigned the Public IP for the `kong-proxy` service.
5. Editing the `helloWorld` ingress like so and changing the `ingressClassName` to `kong`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: hello-kubernetes
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

When the above configs are applied, we get a `404 Not found by Nginx` when visiting the Public IP.

---

*Note:* When we use the `curl http://PUBLIC_IP` inside the Jelastic environment, it loads the `hello kubernetes` application just fine when the `IngressClassName` is set to `kong`. However, it does not work publicly.

We would really appreciate some help on this one. Please and thank you.